# Can you make sure your application is running even on "switch user"?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wix

I have a process that runs under each user and is installed to auto-run on login for each user. When we update, our installer kills all processes of the old version, then installs the new version. For the user installing it, it works as expected, but if a user is "switched user", and comes back, then the application is still dead.

If a user logs off and back on, the auto-launch seems to work just fine. This problem is only affecting users who are "switched".

I imagine the change is going to be in the installer, but not sure if there are other solutions.

Comment: Windows Services might be a thing to look into

Comment: I have a windows service already, and it is using this application to communicate with it. And the application i am replacing is basically the UI. So as a service, I wouldn't have a UI.